# Reversing the encoding of a zipfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zipfile

After decoding this string from base64 I found my string to be malformed?
I'm not really sure about the string and how to convert it to a readable format.

I've tried a few things based on some examples all of which are based around the norm of bytes displayed as 'PK\x03\x04\x14'

```py
decoded = b'PK\\003\\004-\\000\\000\\000\\010\\000\\235-\\366N\\320se\\343\\377\\377\\377\\377\\377\\377\\377\\377\\007\\000\\024\\000VerisEC\\001\\000\\020\\000\\262\\266\\311\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\363Z\\006\\000\\000\\000\\000\\000\\354\\275\\333\\317\\244\\313\\222\\326\\027\\177\\012\\362\\205\\257\\330\\237\\336\\363a\\337Y\\014\\006\\313`,\\206\\361\\011,k\\230\\001\\2145\\006ds\\270\\260\\370\\327m\\177\\021OE}\\313\\330Tfl\\367\\326\\373\\204"\\265\\324\\275\\272\\327\\352\\252z;\\363W\\231qx"\\342\\377\\372?\\377\\017\\371O\\344\\277\\220?\\371\\376\\371\\367\\337?\\026\\371K\\371\\247\\262\\311?\\221S\\216\\357_\\377N\\256\\357\\237\\377\\261\\314\\337\\277\\332\\276\\377Y\\345/\\354\\277]\\337\\277\\332\\276\\177\\365\\217\\277\\377\\371\\363\\357W\\255\\337?\\364\\377\\2562}\\377\\227\\277\\370~\\247\\277\\376\\375\\343\\277\\372\\376\\177\\377\\353\\367{\\371{\\377\\213\\357\\367\\372k\\362\\237~\\377X\\345\\177\\263_\\377\\311\\367\\377\\375W\\362\\257\\345\\177~\\275\\342?\\227\\177\\376\\375_\\376\\352\\373\\377\\375<\\323\\371\\375\\312\\177j\\237\\363\\227\\337\\377\\357\\260\\317\\377\\013{J}\\246E\\356\\357\\377\\247O\\242O\\276|\\377j\\372\\3763\\213\\375<\\177\\377\\327\\345\\373\\237\\353\\373\\317\\375\\371\\353\\023\\376\\364\\373=\\376\\\\\\376w\\371\\227\\337O\\343\\237\\241k\\360\\337|\\377\\327\\277\\222\\177\\363z\\332\\331>U\\377\\374\\177&\\377L\\376\\273\\357\\237\\377\\365\\367?' #Snipped

with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(decoded)) as zf:
    for name in zf.namelist():
        with zf.open(name) as f:
           data = json.loads(f.read().decode())

pprint.pprint(data)
```

Comment: Having it as string in Python 3 won't serve you well here. A (pk)zip blob is collection of bytes. Strings and characters in Python 3 are a more abstract concept and have no intrinsic correspondence to bytes without decoding or encoding between the two.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Your `decoded` variable is a string, not bytes. If you need to declare it statically in the code this way, it probably wants to be something like `decoded = b"PK\x03\x04\x14"` ... etc.

Comment: The string I've exported from a file seems to be a zip file yet I'm unable to read the data from it, how would I get the data from it? 

That's the question, I think I'm getting an incorrect result because I'm not sure how the bytes are delimited. "\\ octal" ? But then how do the extended characters fit into that model?

Comment: Get a bytes object from the file (i.e. `my_zipped_data = open('file.zip', 'rb').read()` - note the `rb`), not a string.

Comment: Octal notation `b'\007'` is equivalent to hex notation `b'\x07'` in what you can represent, it just uses a different number base. The double backslashes are an error, though.

Comment: snip- {"ID":"2df4e76d-8db1-443c-8834-bba2324330bc","Name":"2nd & 3rd Depth","FieldID":"72fbade6-8cf4-429b-bdf2-062061b2284a"- Got it thanks everyone!